# Fixing code which has to replace multiple chars

Tags: python, string

My code:

```
a = "dinaa"
newstr = ''
for char in set(a):
    counts = a.count(char)
    if counts > 1:
        new = a.replace(char, ")")
    else:
        new = a.replace(char, '(')
    print(new)
```

Output from above code:

```
di(aa
d(naa
din))
(inaa
```

Expected output:

```
((())
```

My question: **Any tips how I should fix my code to get *one* output with all changed chars?**

Comment: Did you mean to add `a = new` as the last line of your loop?

Answer (score 0):

like this ?

```py
from collections import Counter
text = "dinaa"
for letter, count in Counter(text).items():
    if count > 1:
        text = text.replace(letter, ")")
    else:
        text = text.replace(letter, "(")
text # '((())'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the intermediate result in each iteration, and then replacing that with a fresh copy of `a`. Presumably you meant to replace in `newstr`, not in `a`?

```
a = "dinaa"
newstr = a
for char in set(a):
    counts = a.count(char)
    if counts > 1:
        newstr = newstr.replace(char, ")")
    else:
        newstr = newstr.replace(char, '(')
print(newstr)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/9Ab1va

Comment: yea i realized that when i read answer from Devyl, now it is working but im trying to figure it out what to do to replace also other chars like '(' or '@'. Input: '((@' should give output: '))(' but i get ')))'

Comment: Try input '((@'

Comment: Because you replace `@` with `(` but then you replace `(` by `)`. This depends on in which order the `set` returns its members so it might differ between Python versions, or even between runs.

Comment: A solution to that would be to use `maketrans` and perform all replacements in one go.

Comment: ok, I found solution. Thanks for help